# How can I add a local drive to a Linux VM with Hyper-V that will stick around after I turn a VPN on inside the VM?

Tags: windows-10, virtual-machine, vpn, hyper-v

I have a Win 10 Pro host, running a Linux Mint VM.

I'd like the VM to always be connected to my VPN (Mullvad). I'd like it to be able to see a folder on my host machine, B:\ISOs. It will download stuff and place it here for me.

I can "share" a local drive while my VPN is off just fine.

Once I turn my VPN on, the drive is no longer accessible. My VPN has an option for "Local Sharing" that is turned on.

I was really hoping that I could just add a folder as a drive like I have with other VM solutions, without having to use the "share" route. But from my research there isn't a way to add a folder as a disk with Hyper-v (but if I'm wrong I'd be very happy).

Any advice would be awesome. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an workaround for Windows 10 - [vhds](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/virtualization/hyper-v/manage/create-vhdset-file)

1. Create VHDS and mount it (as a folder) on host OS.
2. Copy required data to created disk.
3. Attach disk to Linux Mint

Comment: To further clarify: A VHDS is basically a file on the host system that can be mounted simultaneously as a "virtual disk" on both the host and the guest. That gives you shared diskspace between host and guest without having to mount a shared folder (on the host)  as a network-drive (in the VM). The latter is what is blocked by the VPN.